# Password does not match for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to raise a service in my docker-compose to use postgres, I can raise the container correctly, the problem is that it does not allow me to authenticate with the password that I am setting in the environment variables

this is my docker-compose service:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nodejs/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - postgresql

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 00000000
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

what can be the problem here? i trying to get in with pgadmin. In the console show me the error:

```
password authentication failed for user "postgres"
Password does not match for user "postgres".
```

Comment: I am not sure but here's an example of a compose file that has postgres and pgadmin working together if it's of any help: https://github.com/ruairitobrien/docker-dev-setup-example/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 9):

The Postgres password is set on the first initialization if the db (when the var/lib/postgresql/data folder is empty). Since you probably ran docker-compose before with a different password, the new one will not take effect. 
To fix this, remove the volume in your host machine and have docker-compose automatically recreate it next time you run docker-compose up. Note that removing this volume will delete all data stored in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fail with POSTGRES_PASSWORD is to set a password with forbidden characters. You won't get any warnings, but you won't be able to login with this password.

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with your volumes. Try pruning your volumes and then bring up your containers again. MAKE SURE YOU DON'T NEED THE VOLUMES BEFORE YOU PRUNE THEM!

To see what existing volumes you have

```
docker volume ls
```

And then clear them out if you can

```
docker volume prune
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are not runing it first time, you could already change it.
You can manualy edit pg_hba.conf file and set trust authorisation type